# Rails / Devise - signing in a user when session already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app that allows a user to access it as a guest.  My approach to this problem is to automatically add a user if there isn't one in session and set an `is_guest` flag on the user object.  When/if the user creates an account, it actually updates the user credentials rather than creating a new user.  This works perfectly.

I'm running into a corner case when the user tries to log into an existing account after having a guest user.  I initially ran into trouble with the Devise `before_action :require_no_authentication` hook, which I had to override:

```
def require_no_authentication
  return if user_signed_in? and current_user.is_guest?

  super
end
```

That allows the user to actually hit the login page.  But when the user submits the form, the default Session::create method in Devise isn't working:

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

The problem is that, since the session already exists, the sign_in method does nothing.  How can I swap out the user without invalidating the session?

Comment: You may get some use of this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user

Comment: I used that as a guide for the guest user model, but it doesn't mention anything about the situation I'm in.